# How to fix segmentation fault in Linux system call?

Tags: c, linux

I am adding a Linux system call, and I keep getting page faults/segmentation errors and I don't know why. Here's the relevant code:

```
typedef struct _control_entry
{
    struct list_head list;
    int time;
} control_entry;
```

```
void control_update(control_entry* head)
{
        control_entry* pos;

        printk("ENTERING update LOOP");
        list_for_each_entry(pos, &head->list, list)
        {
            printk("ENTERED UPDATE LOOP. IS: %d", pos->time);
            pos->time -= 1;
            printk("FINSIHED PRIMARY DECREMENTATION. IS: %d", pos->time);
            if (pos->time <= 0)
            {
                printk("REMOVING");
                list_del(&pos->list);
                /*
                printk("REMOVING ENTRY");
                pos->list.prev->next = pos->list.next;
                printk("FIRST STAGE DONE");
                pos->list.next->prev = pos->list.prev;
                printk("FINISHED REMOVING ENTRY");
                */
            }
        }
}
```

```
asmlinkage long sys_control(void)
{
    //an array of 100 randomly generatred numbers in the range of 1-1000. Used as the different times each thread will sleep for in this experiment
    //numbers were generated from https://www.random.org/integer-sets/, an online web service that bases its random numbers off of atmosphereic noise
    int sleep_times[] = {532, 58, 542, 573, 924, 379, 753, 183, 268, 254, 803, 188, 794, 936, 976, 585, 755, 189, 905, 880, 911, 396, 889, 348, 629, 515, 830, 107, 452, 47, 857, 650, 14, 524, 548,                     476, 551, 953, 366, 572, 419, 450, 134, 748, 944, 904, 557, 651, 788, 92, 982, 901, 11, 5, 72, 798, 447, 658, 843, 445, 204, 380, 392, 385, 199, 426, 474, 139, 404, 274, 511,                      74, 540, 244, 827, 330, 342, 598, 487, 206, 606, 261, 81, 772, 603, 323, 920, 430, 67, 316, 706, 801, 716, 307, 703, 657, 228, 712, 434, 898};

    int i;
    control_entry chead = {LIST_HEAD_INIT(chead.list), NULL};
    control_entry entry[100];

    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        INIT_LIST_HEAD(&entry[i].list);
        entry[i].time = sleep_times[i];
        list_add(&entry[i].list, &chead.list);
    }

    printk("ENTERING MAIN CONTROL");
    do
    {
        printk("RUNNING MAIN CONTROL");
        control_update(&chead);
        printk("RAN MAIN CONTROL");
        msleep(1);
    }
    while(dq_sizea(&chead.list) > 0);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm relatively new to C and Linux, so I apoligize if it's an obvious mistake. I just cant seem to understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I feel like we need to see more code - can you create a [mcve], please?

Comment: Start by creating a user-space program with this code. Then it's easier to debug it. Once the code works in user-space, copy it to your kernel module (with possible translations like `printf` to `printk` etc.).

Comment: Which "system call" is failing?  A debugger is your best bet.  Inspect the arguments to the failing call _ before_ it is called and check their validity.